# Assign entry id to title with entry form

Tags: entries, form, entry, saveentry

I have an entry form to take user generated content.

The section it passes the info to has a customised title format `Submission ID: {id}`

However, when the entry gets submitted, the title in the CP (and indeed in the templates) just show as `Submission ID:`

It's not until the entry is re-saved at the control panel level (although I haven't tried a front end edit form) that the appropriate id shows e.g. `Submission ID: 12465`

Answer (score 2):

That would be the same behavior for using `{id}` in the title format for new entries created in the control panel as well.

The problem with `{id}` is that's not known until the entry is already saved to the database since it's a database generated number.  That's why it's empty for new entries but re-saving the entry will cause it to appear.

The easiest thing to do would be to generate a [unique ID](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/random.html) from the template and save it to a custom field on the entry.